# 2D Array Buttons Display X and Y

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I have a small program that hold 4 button in a 2D Array what I want to do is display its 'X' and 'Y' coordinates of the Array in a message box (when clicked)

I have tried a number of ways some don't work and some work but I cant get it to show the 'X' and 'Y' values

The image below shows what I have so far:
[image]

And This is the code i have come up with:

```
namespace _2DArray
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Button[,] b;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            b = new Button[2, 2];
            b = new Button[,] { {button1,button2 }, 
                                {button3, button4}};
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button bt in b)
            {
                bt.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickedButton);
            }

        }
        private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = (Button)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button:" + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try assigning some sort of pointer like give name of the button to keep track of it coordinates

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 

                   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                      {
                         for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                         {
                            b[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickedButton);
                            b[i, j].Name =i+" "+j;
                          }
                      }
            }
    private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                Button s = (Button)sender;
                MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button:" + s.Name);
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer to your question if i read it right. You are trying to get the X and Y coordinates of the button right?
Here is the code for a button click:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(button1.Location.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the button location on the form not the array location. I want it to display x=o y=o when button1 is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; x < 2; y++) {
            b[x, y].Tag = new Point(x, y);
            b[x, y].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickedButton);
        }
    }
}

private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button s = (Button) sender;
    MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button:" + s.Tag.ToString());
}
```

then clicking on button1 will show the message "you have clicked button:{X = 0, Y = 0}" etc

Tag is a property that each control has, it's description is "User-defined data associated with the object" so you can set it to whatever object you like.

I know this is probably a bit late for the op but hopefully it will help someone else.